# Change default recognition Mode in Dragon NaturallySpeaking

Tags: windows, naturallyspeaking

Is there any way to change the default recognition mode in Dragon NaturallySpeaking ?

I have found this post - [How to set default recognition Mode in Dragon NaturallySpeaking](http://nuance.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16647/kw/mode)

But it didn't work for me .. Does anyone have changed the default mode successfully ?

---

Specs:

- Windows 7 64 Bit
- Dragon NaturallySpeaking 13

Comment: I tried various entries for "Initial Recognition Mode" and can't get it to work either.  Put in a bug report at Nuance.  Also, you could use a script (AHK) or voice command (if you have a Pro version or add-on (eg KnowBrainer)) to automatically change the recognition mode.  Sorry, for now that's not an answer -- just some solace and advice.

Comment: Nuance replied that it doesn't work:

We apologize for the inconvenience but unfortunately there's no feature for it on Dragon Naturally Speaking. Please submit a feature request on the website below.

http://www.nuance.com/help/contact/feature/

Comment: @PGilm Why can't they submit  a feature request themselves… that's ridiculous. Anyway,I guess you could write your comment as an answer.

Comment: You are right!  I was interested in that feature, too -- especially since the Nuance website said it was doable.  So I logged it as a "bug" and got the response you saw.  I also logged it as a feature request, but haven't received any response.  So, I guess I can now answer the OP . . .  THX,

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, despite what it said in the Nuance customer support link you provided, when I marked this as a "bug," nuance responded that "We apologize for the inconvenience but unfortunately there's no feature for it on Dragon Naturally Speaking. Please submit a feature request on the website below."

So I did add it as a feature request, and I hope you will, too.  Go to: 
http://www.nuance.com/dragon/feature-request/index.htm
Which will re-direct to the forums where you can find feature requests.  Mine is here: http://nuance-community.custhelp.com/posts/3a3bae6684

Here was my initial bug report:

According to this < http://nuance.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16647/kw/mode > I should be able to add a setting in the options.ini file so that my profile starts up in a specific recognition mode (like commands mode). I've tried many ways of changing that setting, but I can't seem to get it to work:

- `Initial Recognition Mode=2`
- `Initial Recognition Mode=Commands`
- `Initial Recognition Mode=Commands Mode`
- etc.

Is this a bug, or am I not doing something correctly (Win 8.1 and DNS13Pro).